# how to pass list of nested object from lwc to apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

**I would like to pass an array of js objects to apex controller. Can anyone please help me on this? How to handle in apex, as I need to store the data in apex as per the below wrapper**

```java
public class ChildWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled
    public Details__c objDetails{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Items> lstItems{get;set;}
    
}
```

```js
[
   {
      "Custom":"No",
      "Platform":"All Devices",
      "Brand":"",
      "SNo":1,
      "lstFlights":[
         {
            "Date":"12/06/2022",
            "End_Date__c":"31/12/2022",
            "SNOfligc":1.01,
         },
         {
            "Date":"12/06/2022",
            "End_Date__c":"31/12/2022",
            "SNOfligc":1.01,
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Custom":"No",
      "Platform":"All Devices",
      "Brand":"",
      "SNo":1,
      "lstFlights":[
         {
            "Date":"12/06/2022",
            "End_Date__c":"31/12/2022",
            "SNOfligc":1.01,
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. pass it as a json string

```
const yourList = [{...}];
const yourListJson = JSON.stringify(yourList);

yourApexMethod({yourListJson : yourListJson})
    .then()
    .catch();
```

2. parse the string into anything you want on the apex side, into a map for example

```
public void yourApexMethod(String yourListJson) {
    Map<String, Object> yourMap = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(yourListJson);
}
```